# Storing large amount of text data for TensorFlow training?

Tags: tensorflow, text

I'm wondering what's the recommended way to store such data in a sequence-to-sequence problem to make it easily usable and efficient with tf.data.Dataset? Basically, I could have a file called data.txt and another called labels.txt and each pair of lines from these lines would be a training example.

Basically I can use tf.data.TextLineDataset, but I would somehow need to translate the text into integer sequences, i.e. indices into my vocabulary. My question is if there's an efficient way to do this translation using Dataset transformations or should I just do the token -> integer translation using my vocabulary as an extra preprocessing step and directly load integer sequence data into the Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Whether to convert strings to ints as a separate processing steps probably depends on your usage scenario. If you are mostly training on fixed vocabulary, it is better to convert to ints once. If you are using the model online and can get new vocabulary items at run time, you will have to allocate new ids online.

Here are a couple of potentially useful pointers:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv - for reading csv formatted data (can read ints/floats)

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup - hashtable like utilities to perform lookups, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_tensor for an example